# Наклон на css, как наклонить бэкграунд? или по другому сделать

Tags: html, css, background, transform

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] как сделать такой наклон? подскажите плиз

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можно попробовать через `transform: skew`. Но я бы добавил уголки через псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after`, это выглядит проще для реализации и дальнейших изменений в адаптиве, например

Comment: спасибо, попробую